# Mystery NullPointerException in PreferencesActivity:onCreate()

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a `PreferencesActivity` that used to work just fine, but is now crashing with a `NullPointerException` when I invoke the activity with an Intent. (I would prefer to use a `PreferencesFragment` but those are not available in `v4.support` libraries).

`

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.app/org.example.app.PrefsActivity} java.lang.NullPointerException
[snipped out some compiler trace]
...
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:567)
at org.example.app.PrefsActivity.onCreate(PrefsActivity.java:16)
[etc]
...
```

the line in question is `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in the `PrefsActivity` class. The class only has one other line in that method, and that is `addPreferenceFromResource(R.xml.prefs);`. Other than `onCreate`, the Activity is pretty much empty.

The activity is registered in the manifest file and the xml is correct (which it isn't getting a chance to load anyway). This problem occurs on all devices I have tried it on, emulators, phones and tablets, running anything from Gingerbread to Jellybean.

I am using emacs/ant and have cleaned the project. The prefs activity is being called in a basic Intent code block from within a `Fragment`:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PrefsActivity.class);

    startActivity(i);
```

Can anyone elaborate as to what's happening?

Comment: Odd error;it is probably caused by something else though. How are you calling PreferenceActivity and did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: Project has been cleaned multiple times. I am using emacs/ant so it is not anything related to Eclipse. I will update the question.

Comment: Check if your getActivity() returned your activity.

Comment: Well `savedInstanceState` can be null without errors, so I doubt that's the cause. Is that Exception the last part of the stack trace?

Comment: Are you using ActivitySherlock? Try using getSherlockActivity() in that case

Comment: Thank you all. The getActivity() call is correct - MainActivity. It's the same one that is hosting all the Tabs. The Bundle savedInstanceState is null. I am not using ActivitySherlock -- should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a rewrite, I figured out the problem.

I had omitted the @Override annotation from the onCreate method. That was it.

Comment: If someone can explain why this is, I'll mark that as an answer. I'm guessing the Android framework requires it.